# Is there a python function to get columns according to NaN percentage?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,1], p=(0.8,0.2),size=(10,10)))
print (df)
```

```
     0    1    2   3    4    5    6   7    8   9
0  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN
3  1.0  1.0  NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN
5  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN
6  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN
8  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN
```

For the above `dataframe`, what's the simplest code to get `column names` which are below the given **NAN percentage**(threshold)?

To get the column names that are below 30% NaN, I'm able to do this using the below code

```
col_list = df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[0]*0.3, 
                     how='all', axis=1).columns.to_list()

col_list
```

```
[0, 4, 6, 8]
```

What's the simplest code to get such column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

```
col_list = df.columns[df.count() / df.shape[0] >= 0.3].tolist()
print(col_list)

# Output:
[0, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I want to return the column names which are below 30% NaN

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
df.isna().mean().loc[lambda x : x<0.3]
Out[59]: 
1    0.1
6    0.2
7    0.0
8    0.2
dtype: float64
# df.notna().mean().loc[lambda x : x<0.3].index
```

Comment: This returns column that is above 30% NaN.

Comment: @Pluviophile Got u , fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do it via indexing, something like that should work

```py
df.columns[df.isna().sum() / df.shape[0] < 0.3] # columns names
df.loc[:, df.isna().sum() / df.shape[0] < 0.3] # columns with data
```

So, computing the fraction of nums, getting if that is below the threshold, and using loc to extract the respective columns.